# Norm inequality problem on a finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality, riemannian-geometry, geometric-inequalities

[image]

My question is how do we prove that last inequality?

Comment: Hint: The eigenvectors form a ONB w.r.t. $g$.